# Compare variables with unit suffixes in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need a help on below she’ll script

Suppose we have 2 variables which will get values dynamically in sizes byes kb me gb

Var1 = 25 mb it can be in any size either in bytes or kb or mb or gb

Var2 = 1 gb it can be in any size either in bytes or kb or mb or gb

Now I need to compare these values, if var1 size is less than var2 size then proceed else come out.

Pls help I am very new to bash scripting

I am new to shell not getting how to write this

Comment: Be specific -- for this to be answerable we need pseudocode like `Var1 = 25 mb`, but _actual code_, like `Var1="25 mb"` (if in fact that's what your variable looks like). Similarly, if it's really `25mb` instead of `25 mb`, that difference matters too.

Comment: Anyhow -- the obvious thing to do is to recognize the suffixes, trim them, and multiply appropriately so you get a value in bytes for ready comparison. Is there a specific place you need help with to be able to do that?

Comment: I can trim the variables values but not getting how to compare size of different variables values pls help on complete script

Comment: Again, I can't write an answer and know it's correct until I know what your input looks like, not just in a rough/pseudocode way but _exactly_.

Comment: Thanks Charles variable 1 values always need to be trimmed and then compare to variable 2 which doesn’t require any trim

Comment: [Edit] the question to show those variables defined according to the above spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the prefix, multiply appropriately. See this running at https://ideone.com/YC1ghB

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
size_re='^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*([kmg])b?[[:space:]]*$'

declare -A multipliers=(
  [k]=$(( 1024 ))
  [m]=$(( 1024 * 1024 ))
  [g]=$(( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))
)

to_bytes() {
  result=$1
  if [[ $1 =~ $size_re ]] && { units=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; [[ $units && ${multipliers[$units]} ]]; }; then
    result=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} * ${multipliers[${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]} ))
  elif (( $1 )); then
    result=$(( $1 ))
  else
    echo "ERROR: $1 could not be parsed as a number" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo "$result"
}

Var1='25 MB'
Var2=1G
Var1_bytes=$(to_bytes "${Var1,,}") || exit
Var2_bytes=$(to_bytes "${Var2,,}") || exit
if (( Var1_bytes > Var2_bytes )); then
  echo "Var1 is larger than Var2"
else
  echo "Var1 is not larger than Var2"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much Charles. It’s very difficult to understand for beginners. 

Is declare -A multiplier is array ??

Comment: `-a` is regular arrays, `-A` is "associative arrays", which other languages call maps. (They're really both maps under the hood, but the `-a` ones are numerically-indexed, the `-A` ones are string-indexed)

Comment: Thanks and $1 is considered a first argument here it is var1. If possible pls explain each line in brief so that being a beginner I can understand. Especially to_bytes function

Comment: It'd be easier if you could ask specific questions about any patterns you're having trouble finding documentation for.

Comment: ...the main thing to know is that `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` sets the array `BASH_REMATCH` to contain the match groups found in that regex. Also, `${array[$key]}` is how someone does a lookup in a bash array (associative or otherwise). Anything else unclear?

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles. It’s clear now and set -x explain in details.

Comment: Hi Charles, sorry need help again. I tried this and it’s working very well. By mistake I gave var2 values wrongly it should be always in G/M/K instead of gb mb or kb and there won’t be any space in between digit and unit. Pls help

Comment: For ex Var1 is 25 mb and var2 is 1G

Comment: Var1 is 25 MB and var2 is 1G

Comment: Is `G` intended to be Gb or GB in that case? (That is to say, can you just ignore the `b` when it's there?) -- if so, I'd add a `?` after the `b` in the regex to make it optional, and change `to_bytes "$Var1"` to `to_bytes "${Var1,,}"` to convert the data to lower case before passing it in. (Note that that's syntax added in bash 4.0 and won't work in versions older than that).

Comment: I will always get var1 value as digit space capital letter unit like MB GB TB and var2 value as digit nospace capital letter unit like 1G /2T

Comment: Pls help Charles

Comment: @Chandan, ...see edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles. I failed again here I am getting Var1 values in decimal and integer both, i am failing to convert to integer . I can’t expect more from you. Thanks a lot its very useful and learnt something new

Comment: Sorry to ask u again any help pls again ? I am not getting this for integer and floating value

Comment: Which part? _Capturing_ the floating-point values, or _calculating_ with them? For the latter, see [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022); for the former, change `[[:digit:]]+` to `[[:digit:].]+`

Comment: I am getting var1 values both integer and floating values

Comment: Var1 = 256.45 MB

Comment: And sometimes integer values also reg exp has to check both int and flit values

Comment: Size_re should check  both integer and float values

Comment: Currently I am getting var1 value is 2.937 MB and I have updated above changes to size_re but getting below this error line 13: 2.937 * 1048576 : Syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator error token in “.937 * 1048576 “)

Comment: With size_re I need to capture both integer or float values pls help

Comment: That syntax error tells me you didn't follow the advice to update your code as described in [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022). You need to make both changes, not just the regex change alone.

Comment: Pls help on reg exp to capture both int and float

Comment: Var1 =125MB or 123.4MB

Comment: Var2=123M or 1.1T

Comment: I am trying but not working

Comment: Getting could not be parsed as number value too great for base

Comment: Ask a new question, showing your work and a [mre].